# `kill "$!"` doesn't work when FOR loop is around

Tags: linux, bash

It seems that **kill "$!"** command doesn't work if FOR loop is involved.

The script below triggers 2 functions, main and the progress, to run simultaneously. Once the main is done, the progress being killed:

```
#!/bin/bash

functionA() { # MAIN
    sleep 15     
}

functionB() { #PROGRESS
    local A=${1:-30} 
    local B=${2:-1} 
    local C=${3:-"X"} 
    local D=${4:-"*"} 
    local i

    while true        
    do
        echo -en "["
        for i in $(seq 1 "$A")
        do
                echo -en "$C"
        done

        echo -en "]\0015["
        for i in $(seq 1 "$A")
        do
            echo -en "$D"
            sleep "${B}"
        done
        echo
    done
}

functionB 10 &         
progress_PID="$!"

functionA 

kill "$progress_PID"   # Stop the progress bar
echo "Finished"
```

It works very well.

However, when i put into the **functionA** the real code it should use, that contains a ***FOR*** loop, the progress never ends, despite the main function has finished a long ago:

```
functionA() {
        for IP in "${book[@]}"; do
                ssh user@"$IP" "sleep 15" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
        done
wait
}
```

I tried to add *echo "$!"* to catch if the "$!" is caught well. It is, the process ID is constant, but i cannot see it in the shell because probably it exists only in subshell.

Why the **progress_PID="$!"** is not being killed, despite it is obviously being aught?

(Please explain the solution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your `wait` is also waiting for the backgrounded progress bar. Try capturing the specific pids of the backgrounded `ssh` instances, and waiting on them specifically:

```
functionA() {
        local a=()

        for IP in "${book[@]}"; do
                ssh user@"$IP" "sleep 15" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
                a+=($!)
        done

        wait "${a[@]}"
}
```

This places the pids of backgrounded `ssh`es into an array, then waits on the members of the array rather than "everything that is backgrounded", which is `wait`'s default behaviour. The bash man page states:

> If n̲ is not given, all currently active child processes are waited for

Note: untested. May contain nuts.